# По какому алгоритму Пайтон находит остсток от деления?

Tags: python

Мне нужен именно алгоритм, я хочу понять, каким образом программа при действии 6.5 % 2 понимает, что ответ 0.5

Comment: гораздо интереснее, почему -6.5 % 2 = 1.5 ;)

Comment: Да это как раз очевидно.

Comment: [How does Python implement the modulo operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18200092/2881286) а так же [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c посмотрите реализацию `long_mod`

Answer (score 1):

6.5 // 2 = 3
6.5 - (2 * 3) = 0.5

-6.5 // 2 = -4
-6.5 - (2 * -4) = 1.5

Comment: это понятно, но какой тогда алгоритм у целочисленного деления?

Answer (score 0):

В арифметике `Euclidean division` - или деление с остатком - это процесс деления одного числа (делимого) на другое (делитель) таким образом, чтобы получить частное и остаток, меньшие, чем делитель.

Comment: Вы не ответили на суть вопроса, я попросил дать мне алгоритм нахождения остатка от деления, а не определение деления с остатком

Comment: @Тимофей вы видимо хотите переопределить эти действия? Вам надо посмотреть исходный код для  этого действия.

Comment: А не подскажете, где я могу его найти?

Comment: @Тимофей  попробуйте посмотреть здесь https://github.com/python/cpython

Comment: Благодарю, помогли

Comment: @Тимофей   Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour